# Perl readline problem

Tags: perl, readline

I'd to read a file, e.g. `test.test` which contains

```
 #test:testdescription\n
 #cmd:binary\n
 #return:0\n
 #stdin:|\n
 echo"toto"\n
 echo"tata"\n
 #stdout:|\n
 toto\n
 tata\n
 #stderr:\n
```

I succeeded in taking which are after #test: ; #cmd: etc...
but for `stdin` or `stdout`, I want to take all the line before the next `#` to a table `@stdin` and `@stdout`.

I do a loop `while ($line = <TEST>)` so it will look at each line. If i see a pattern `/^#stdin:|/`, I want to move to the next line and take this value to a 
table until i see the next `#`.

How do I move to the next line in the `while` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This file format can be easily handled with some creativity in selecting the appropriate value for [`$/`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%2f):

```
use strict; use warnings;

my %parsed;

{
    local $/ = '#';
    while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
        chomp $line;
        my $content = (split /:/, $line, 2)[1];
        next unless defined $content;
        $content =~ s/\n+\z//;
        if ( my ($chan) = $line =~ /^(std(?:err|in|out))/ ) {
            $content =~ s/^\|\n//;
            $parsed{$chan} = [ split /\n/, $content];
        }
        elsif ( my ($var) = $line =~ /^(cmd|return|test)/ ) {
            $parsed{ $var } = $content;
        }
    }
}

use YAML;
print Dump \%parsed;

__DATA__
#test:testdescription
#cmd:binary
#return:0
#stdin:|
echo"toto"
echo"tata"
#stdout:|
toto
tata
#stderr:
```

Output:

```
---
cmd: binary
return: 0
stderr: []
stdin:
  - echo"toto"
  - echo"tata"
stdout:
  - toto
  - tata
test: testdescription
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED as per user's colmments**

If I understand the question correctly, you want to read one more line within a loop?

If so, you can either:

1. just do another line read inside the loop.

   ```
   my $another_line = <TEST>;
   ```
2. Keep some state flag and use it next iteration of the loop, and accumulate lines between stdins in a buffer:

   ```
   my $last_line_was_stdin = 0;
   my @line_buffer = ();
   while ($line = <TEST>) {
       if (/^#stdin:|/) {
           #
           # Some Code to process all lines acccumulated since last "stdin"
           #
           @line_buffer = ();
           $last_line_was_stdin = 1;
           next;
       }
       push @line_buffer, $line;
   }
   ```

   This solution may not do 100% of what you need but it defines a pattern you need to follow in your state machine implementation: read a line. Check your current state (if it matters). Based on the current state and a pattern in the line, verify what do do about the current line (add to the buffer? change the state? If changing a state, process the buffer based on last state?)

Also, as per your comment, you have a bug in your regex - the pipe (`|` character) means "OR" in regex, so you are saying "if line starts with `#stdin` OR matches an empty regex" - the latter part is always true so your regex will match 100% of time. You need to escape the "|" via `/^#stdin:\|/` or `/^#stdin:[|]/`

Comment: one more thing: when i put in 
while ($line = <TEST>)
{
if($line =~ /^stdin:|/)
{
print "line ";
}
}
it print all lines in the file .Normally it should only print #stdin:| right?

Comment: the second solution doesnt solve the problem cause i want all line after | until i meet a #

Comment: @viet - so extend it to read in a line and append to array/accumulating scalar until the next stdin is found. Also, when stdin is found, instead of "next"-ing to next line, first process the whole buffer/accumulator and empty it out. I edited the answer accordingly

Comment: @Viet - escape the "|" in your regex. Use "\|" or "[|]". I edited my answer

Comment: I have a problem also. when  a read a line then i do push @stdin, $line,